# Creating new Sphere in Unity Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game in Unity 3D for android phones.
Currently I'm using sphere as my main object.
I just want to ask if how I could create another sphere
in the scene once first ball is thrown and disappear.
It just like another ball to shoot in basketball game.It will continue 
to have a sphere/ball until time is already zero.
Thank you.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it please.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Prefabs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Prefabs.html). You just need to create a prefab out of your GameObject and can then create new instances using the [Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

Answer (score 0):

`var sphere : GameObject = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);`
[CreatePrimitive Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PrimitiveType.Sphere.html)

If you don't want the basic sphere you'll have to Instantiate a prefab like Kay says in his Answer.

```
var prefab : Transform;
function OnTriggerEnter () {
    Instantiate (prefab);
}
```

[Instantiate Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to Instantiate the ball when you need a new ball. Following sample code might help you:

```
public GameObject ball;
bool isBallThrown;         //trigger that to true when ball is to be thrown 
void Update(){
     if(isBallThrown){
     Instantiate(ball,new Vector3(2,3,0),Quaternion.identity));
          isBallThrown=false;
     }
}
```

Attach the sphere to ball GameObject..